# Android ActivityManager showing every 2 secs that the application is open?

Tags: android

Can anyone please help me ?
Here is my alarmmanager code that will open up the service after every 2 seconds..

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = 
    (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 2*1000 , pintent);
```

And here is my code for checking running application

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) 
    this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
   if((procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.android.browser") 
        && procInfos.get(i).importance==procInfos.get(i).IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND)) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Browser is running",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The problem is that when the browser is open a toast appears every 2 secs. How should I make this appear only once as the browser gets foreground ? Really need some help

Thank You !